# bcp command not working

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using the following bcp command

```
BCP "select * from PACIFIC.dbo.CEOExtractCorpRulesView with(nolock) " 
   queryout "d:\temp\CEOExtractCorpRulesView.txt" 
   -S"tcp:BCBWEC-VIRTD2\SQL2005" -c -t"|!" -U"userid" -P"password"
```

I get an error every time

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

Please let me know what the problem might be. This is not my script.

Thanks

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: How are you running this script? In a command prompt?

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error if I try and execute this script by pasting it into SSMS and clicking execute.

AFAIK you need to open a command window and run this.

Comment: @user - If you just open a command prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd) and paste that in it should work hopefully. If not report back on the error.

Comment: @user387268 - What error did it give you? There are quite a few possibilities (bcp not in your `PATH`, wrong server name, wrong login credentials) and it is impossible for me to guess!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to `xp_cmdshell` you can call bcp from that

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select * from PACIFIC.dbo.CEOExtractCorpRulesView with(nolock) " 
   queryout "d:\temp\CEOExtractCorpRulesView.txt" 
   -S"tcp:BCBWEC-VIRTD2\SQL2005" -c -t"|!" -U"userid" -P"password" '
```

NOTE: I have not checked the above for proper character escaping...  That's a pain.

Otherwise, you will have to run bcp from command line.  It's a command-line tool.  The T-SQL interpreter knows nothing of it.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Martin.  BCP is for the C prompt not for SQL Server Management Studio.  To run it inside SSMS you need to use xp_cmdshell (and be logged as a user with rights to get to xp_cmdshell).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like command line syntax to me.  I don't think it works in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Running BCP in command prompt with admin rights with unc path seem to work